# Only displaying overlapping date ranges from the same table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to create bit of SQL that will bring back any records where the start and end dates may overlap from another record.

Example Table 1:

[image: Table 1]

Using the code below it does work, however I wanted to add 2 extra parameters. But as soon as I attempt to add them it takes a long time to generate and when it does, it brings back records that don't overlap with any other records.

I am hoping to bring back results like in Table 2 below. Essentially I want it to bring back:

- overlapping date records
- that are between 01/05/2018 - 31/03/2018
- and that have a employee count of 4 or more.

See example Table 2 of what I am expecting:

[image: Table 2 - expected results]

```
select t1.*
from Table_1 t1
where exists (select 1
              from Table_2 t2
              where t1.Record_ref <> t2.Record_ref and
                    t1.Start_date_and_time  < t2.Finish_date_&_time and
                    t1.Finish_date_&_time > t2.Start_date_and_time  and
                    (t1.Start_date_and_time  <> t2.Start_date_and_time  or  -- filter out the record itself
                     t1.Finish_date_&_time <> t2.Finish_date_&_time)
             )
AND (t1.Start_date_and_time >= '2016-05-01 00:00:00.000' AND t1.Start_date_and_time < '2016-05-01 00:00:00.000' AND t1.Employee_count >= '4')
order by t1.Start_date_and_time;
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: In standard SQL you could do `where t1.Record_ref <> t2.Record_ref and (t1.Start_date_and_time, t1.Finish_date_&_time) overlaps (t2.Start_date_and_time, t2.Finish_date_&_time)`

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Pictures of your data are bad. Tables of your data are good.  Here's a [link to build simple tables from text](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/).

Comment: Why did you replace the formatted text data with pictures?

Comment: I'm a bit lost.  I do not see no overlaps in the sample data for the two records that you want.  The time frames don't even match what you specify.

Comment: Sorry!  It was my first post and my tables wouldn't copy and paste correctly. Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name I'll check that link out. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I tired using the "overlaps" in the code and it says it is non-Boolean.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the end time and date for one record is after the start time and date of another record.